# Java - Store the changing int variable

Tags: java

So I'm trying to write the most simple game , everytime "the monster" attacks "the player" I want the variable "int totalHealth" to be lowered .

```
public void attack(Player somePlayer) {

    int totalHealth = somePlayer.getHitPoints() + somePlayer.getStrength();

    int remainingHealth = totalHealth - damage;
    if (remainingHealth == 0 || remainingHealth < 0) {
        System.out.println("Your player died");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The monster attacked " + somePlayer.getName() + " and made " + this.damage + " damage");
        System.out.println("Your remaining health is - " + (remainingHealth - somePlayer.getStrength()));
    }

}
```

But the problem is that variable "remainingHealth" stays same , only the first time when I run the code it lowers , every next time it stays same,  I guess the problem is in this line :

```
int totalHealth = somePlayer.getHitPoints() + somePlayer.getStrength();
```

I guess everytime I run the code

```
somePlayer.getHitpoints()
```

takes the inserted integer from constructor and that's the problem.

I need to figure out the way to store the remaining health in a variable somehow

Player class :

```
public class Player implements ISavable{

private String name;
private int hitPoints ;
private int strength ;
private String weapon;
private int damage;
private int totalHealth = hitPoints + strength;

public Player(String name, int damage , int hitPoints , int strength) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    this.weapon = "Sword";
    this.hitPoints = hitPoints;
    this.strength = strength;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getHitPoints() {
    return hitPoints;
}

public void setHitPoints(int hitPoints) {
    this.hitPoints = hitPoints;
}

public int getStrength() {
    return strength;
}

public void setStrength(int strength) {
    this.strength = strength;
}

public String getWeapon() {
    return weapon;
}

public void setWeapon(String weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
}

public int getTotalHealth() {
    return totalHealth;
}

public void setTotalHealth(int totalHealth) {
    this.totalHealth = totalHealth;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Player{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", hitPoints=" + hitPoints +
            ", strength=" + strength +
            ", weapon='" + weapon + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public List<String> write() {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add(0, this.name);
    values.add(1, "" + this.hitPoints);
    values.add(2, "" + this.strength);
    values.add(3, "" + this.weapon);
    values.add(4,"" + this.damage);
    return values;
}

@Override
public void read(List<String> savedValues) {
    if (savedValues != null && savedValues.size()>0){
        this.name = savedValues.get(0);
        this.hitPoints = Integer.parseInt(savedValues.get(1));
        this.strength = Integer.parseInt(savedValues.get(2));
        this.weapon = savedValues.get(3);
    }
}

public void attack(Monster someMonster){
    int health = someMonster.getHitPoints();
    int remainingHealth = health - damage;
    if (remainingHealth == 0 || remainingHealth < 0) {
        System.out.println("You killed the monster !!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You attacked the monster " + " and made " + this.damage + " damage");
        System.out.println("Monsters remaining health is - " + remainingHealth);
    }

    if (someMonster.isDead()){
        this.hitPoints = 100;
        this.strength = 50;
    }
}

public void healPlayer(Player somePlayer){
    int hp = somePlayer.getHitPoints();
    hp += 10;
    System.out.println("You healed the player for 10hp , your current hp is " + hp);
}
```

}

Comment: keep that as an instance variable as well, on construction, set that to hitpoints + strength, and lower that value when he's hit

Comment: Put `totalHealth ` out of the function and keep it updated

Comment: `totalHealth` is instanciated every time you call `attack` - so if it doesn´t change the value (only once), have a look at the player-values. Add logging for totalHealth and the player-values.  print actual and expected.

Comment: @canillas if the `player`-Values was changed between the `attack()`-calls it will be updated and right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the value of totalHealth, you initialize it everytime that attack() method is called, so you always have the same Health.

You can solve it putting out of the attack() method the line:

```
int totalHealth = somePlayer.getHitPoints() + somePlayer.getStrength();
```

**EDIT:**

```
public void attack(Player somePlayer) {

    somePlayer.totalHealth = somePlayer.totalHealth - this.damage;
    if (somePlayer.totalHealth.equals(0) || somePlayer.totalHealth < 0) {
        System.out.println("Your player died");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The monster attacked " + somePlayer.getName() + " and made " + this.damage + " damage");
        System.out.println("Your remaining health is - " + (somePlayer.totalHealth - somePlayer.getStrength()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes but I can't do it with "somePlayer" because it's something I passed in the method.

Comment: @TornikeShelia Your Player class has an health attribute?Can you share with us your Player class?

Comment: @TornikeShelia As I can see, you just have an health attribute into your player, so you don't need to calculate the totalHealth again because it's declared in your player class. Check my edit.

Comment: I checked it , but somehow it doesn't calculate the right amount of health,  I've set the damage of the "Monster" to 6  and the health of "Player" to 100 but every time I run the attack method the "Player" dies,  I'll try to find the problem

Comment: I figured it out, problem was that I wasn't passing the  totalHealth to the constructor,  Thank you so much , It works now and I figured out how to make it work in the future . :)

Comment: @TornikeShelia I'm glad to have been helped you

Answer (score 0):

On `Player` create a function `updateHealth(int newHealth)` that sets the variable returned from `getHitPoints()` to `newHealth`. Then just append `somePlayer.updateHealth(somePlayer.getHitPoints() - damage);` at the end of the `attack` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a representation of health, defining in Player `totalHealth`.

You may use a method which calculate the total health (cause your player could get an item that increases strenght or an item that allow heal you).

Then you should use another variable in Player, remainingHealth and initialize it as `remainingHealth = totalHealth`

```
    public class Player {

    float totalHealth;
    float remainingHealth;
    ...

    public Player(...) {
        this.remainingHealth = this.totalHealth;
        ...
    }
    ...

}
```

When you want decrease the health of your player you should use remainingHealth.

```
    public void attack(Player somePlayer) {

    somePlayer.remainingHealth -= this.damage;
    if (somePlayer.remainingHealth <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Your player died");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The monster attacked ...");
        System.out.println("Your remaining health is - " + somePlayer.remainingHealth);
    }

}
```